# WordPress before posting check if the post title exists and redirect to the oldest post instead of creating a new one

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using user-submitted-posts plugin in order to let the guests post on my WordPress website.

I want to be able to identify if the title written by the user is already available and redirect the user to the existing post instead of creating a new post or to redirect and delete the newly created post. I tried to create some code that should work but I am not sure where should I put the code in order to catch the title before the post is created.
If it helps, this is my website [www.epic-review.com](http://www.epic-review.com)

```
function implode_all($glue, $arr) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if (@is_array($arr[$i])) 
            $arr[$i] = implode_all ($glue, $arr[$i]);
    }
    return implode($glue, $arr);
}

global $wpdb;
$titlul=get_the_title();
$titles = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_title='$titlul' ", ARRAY_A);
$resultUrl = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT guid from $wpdb->posts where post_title='$titlul'", ARRAY_A);
$finalUrl = implode_all(", ",$resultUrl);

if ($titles) {
    wp_redirect("$finalUrl");
    exit;
}
```

I also tried this in functions.php but it didn't work.

```
function implode_all($glue, $arr){            
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    if (@is_array($arr[$i])) 
        $arr[$i] = implode_all ($glue, $arr[$i]);
}            
return implode($glue, $arr);
}
function wp_exist_post_by_title( $title ) {
global $wpdb;
//$title= $_POST['post_title'];
$returnID = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title 
like '%$title%' && post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'post' order by 
ID limit 1", 'ARRAY_N' );
$resultReturnID = implode_all(", ",$returnID);
$linkPost = get_permalink("$resultReturnID");
if( empty( $returnID ) ) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}

// usage
if( wp_exist_post_by_title( $post->name ) ) {
wp_redirect("$linkPost");
} 
else { 
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
```